# Create a C# dictionary from DB query with repeated keys

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a Database with schools, and each school is in a City. 
Now I want to create a dictionary that contains all the cities of each schoool. To achieve this I tried this approach:

```
var schoolCities = schoolsWithAddresses.Where(school => school.Address.City != null).ToDictionary(sc => sc.Address.City.Name.ToLower());
```

Now, the problem with this is that a City can have multiple schools. So, when I create my dictionary, I end up with an exception "Repeated Key".

I want to create a dicitonary because it will allow me to make a very quick lookup on the cities that have schools (that is why I am not using a List, for example).

How do I overcome this problem in a way rhat allows me to still make efficient lookups?

Comment: create a Dictionary<string,List<School>> instead. You need a unique key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ToLookUp extension method rather

```
var schoolCities = schoolsWithAddresses
.Where(school => school.Address.City != null)
.ToLookup(sc => sc.Address.City.Name.ToLower());
```

Answer (score 1):

You should group the items first, so that you have unique cities.

```
schoolsWithAddresses.Where(school => school.Address.City != null)
.GroupBy(s => s.Address.City, (k, v) => new { City = k, Schools = v })
.ToDictionary(d => d.City, e => e.Schools)
;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is a [`Lookup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx):

> Represents a collection of keys each mapped to one or more values.

Example usage:

```
Lookup<string, School> schoolCities = schoolsWithAddresses
    .Where(school => school.Address.City != null)
    .ToLookup(school => school.Address.City);

IEnumerable<School> schoolsInLondon = schoolCities["London"];
```

Comment: Should it not be `.ToLookup(school => school.Address.City.Name.ToLower());` instead ? This sounds cool, I'll experiment !

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix Depends how you want to access it. If it is case sensitive you can keep it as above, if it isn't then you can use `ToLower` or `ToUpper` as you like and access it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, List<School>> schoolCities = schoolsWithAddresses
            .Where(school => school.Address.City != null)
            .GroupBy(school => school.Address.City)
            .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var schoolCities = schoolsWithAddresses
.GroupBy(x => x.city!=null)
.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());
```